# Zend Gdata Library - Connection Timeout

Tags: php, google-docs, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

I am having a new problem with the Zend Gdata library where I am regularly receiving this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://spreadsheets.google.com:443. Error #110: Connection timed out'
```

I have not changed any of my code and I have been using the same code successfully for a long time now. What I find even stranger, is that if I take the code from my domain ([www.mattblubaugh.com](http://www.mattblubaugh.com)) and I copy it to one of my other domains ([www.ryanemiller.com/external/mattblubaugh](http://www.ryanemiller.com/external/mattblubaugh)) I don't experience the timeout. In addition, the second domain is using the same Zend Gdata library to pull in most of its content. There is no problem there.

I have scoured Google and have come across a sparse number of people complaining about this problem, but most are from over a year ago.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

[edit 10:02pm]

I have tried the files locally via WAMP and have no problems. The problematic host is with inmotionhosting. Does anyone else have this host and have you experienced timeout problems recently?

Comment: Please provide your code that is producing this error.  I just tested https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full and it worked fine.

Comment: This has since been resolved. It was a problem with my host provider, not my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been resolved. It was a problem with my host provider, not my code.

Comment: can you specify the problem with your host? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the specific problem was. My host migrated me to a new server running PHP 5.3 and that seemed to fix the problem. The suggestion they made to me prior to the migration was to check and see if the host IP address was being blocked by Google. As best I could tell it wasn't. What version of PHP are you running? Also, if you have additional web hosting available, I would recommend testing your code there to see if the problem persists. For me, I had no issues with the same code on a different host and used this to leverage my support request.

Answer (score 7):

We had the same problem for a few days. The actual problem was `IPv6`. The server resolved `google.com` to an `IPv6` address first and tried to connect with that. This caused a time-out.
I checked it by running `telnet google.com 443`, here you can see if it resolves to an `IPv4` or `IPV6` address. After I turned of the `IPv6` lookup, the exception was gone.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But how do I turn off IPv6 lookup on dreamhost's server?